# HTTPS connection from c# client to Tomcat using wsdl.exe

Tags: c#, .net, tomcat, https, wsdl.exe

I have a tomcat webservice and a c# .net client that connects to the service. I created the Connection classes with wsdl.exe and everything is fine. But now i have activated ssl in tomcat to use https. In my c# app i only changed the url to https and i get the following error:

**The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.**

How do i avoid this message? is this because the cretificate is untrusted? How do i tell my client that this connection is trusted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, most likely the server's certificate isn't trusted for your client.
You can handle the `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` to allow SSL connections to the invalid certificated servers:

```
private static bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors policyErrors)
{
    return true; // allow connection despite any errors
}    
...
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ValidateRemoteCertificate;
```